# Passing a Java Result to JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have recently been thrown into the wonderful world of programming websites with Java. I have a little experience with Java but would still consider myself a beginner.

I have created a Java class that has a simple SQL query in it. I am trying to display onto a JSP page but am unsure on how to achieve this.

Here is my Java class called Main.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    //Accessing driver from JAR
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
    //jdbc:mysql://host_name:port/dbname
    //Driver name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select name from user");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    while(result.next()) {
        System.out.println(result.getString(1));
    }
}
```

How would I get `system.out.println` on a JSP page?

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to actually work with raw JSPs these days. You should see what framework your job will actually be using and look for the tutorials for that specific framework. I wouldn't worry about learning the low-level stuff in detail first - by now servlets are something you use to write web frameworks, not applications, and JSPs are more or less a legacy technology. (And the Java EE tutorial has you covered there: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: it's for a uni assignment and the text/information being taught is rather outdated.

Comment: The Java EE 5 tutorial is the last one that seemed to deal with Servlets+JSP at length: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html . It doesn't really deal with how to get the application to run in a container though. If you're allowed to use IDEs, I'd poke around whichever one you're using to help with that.

Comment: (I'll admit I'm somewhat at a loss of how to explain this from beginning to end. Java EE is *completely terrible* at getting a newbie from 0 to 60 - answering a question as seemingly trivial as this while assuming only basic previous knowledge involves discussing a lot of moving parts. Most of what I know has gradually seeped in via osmosis suring practice rather than been cohesively explained to me. If I was to teach this in a programming course, I'd probably provide some sort of student test server where they could simply copy their code to - maybe check if you have one available?)

Comment: essentially we need to create a website that allows users to submit some basic information to a database and then also be able to retrieve that information

Comment: If that's the sum of your assignment description, AND you don't have any test server provided, AND you're not *explicitly* told to use Servlets+JSP… I'd act the alibist and use JSF instead which is described in the Java EE 6 tutorial in a way that's actually somewhat useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html. While JSF is way overkill for a task this simple the "use NetBeans and click on these buttons to run the code" style of documentation should get you up and running quickly. (Alternately clear this with your instructor.)

Comment: One side benefit would be that JSF will get you started with using reasonable practices. (Which using scriptlets in JSP pages as some of the answers suggest isn't - doing so is valid grounds to have your supervisor apply a clue stick.)

Comment: Unfortunately we have been told to use jsp, servlets

Comment: Hm, I seem to recall IBM DeveloperWorks had decent tutorial-level material available. Try taking a look at these then: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-intserv/index.html, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-introjsp/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save results and display to JSP .

save the results in request and in view layer iterate using JSTL to display the result.
which means , in servlet get the request and forward it new jsp

I recommend to use JSF instead JSP ,

Comment: im sorry but would you be able to point me to tutorial or something else that would show me how to do this?

Comment: Refer to this tutorial :  http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/14-MVC.pdf

Answer (score 0):

JSP also allows you to write blocks of Java code inside the JSP.  You do this by placing your Java code between <% and %> characters.
A scriptlet contains Java code that is executed every time the JSP is invoked.
Here is a link to simple jsp web app that should help you to get started.

http://j2ee.masslight.com/Chapter1.html#mygreeting

Answer (score 0):

you could use below sample code as a reference.

```
JSP page
       <form action="servlet1" method="get">
        <%   ModelClass class = new ModelClass();
        class.connectDb();
        class.performDBoperations();
          %>
       <table><tr><td>
      <%   
              class.id;     
       %> 
       </form>

Model Class:
        class ModelClass {
          int id;
            public static void connectDb() {
               dbConnection code
               }
             public void performDBoperations() {
                  get info from table with SQL thru JDBC.
                    id=update it;  
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic concept in web programming is that you don't start actions from a method (`main` or any other). Someone request's a JSP or servlet and the corresponding class answers. You can do both things in a JSP and leave the work of connecting to a database to an auxiliar class as @chaitanya10 answer shows.

The Nebeans [tutorial for JSP's](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html) is not a bad starting point. There are several JSP/Servlets tutorial in the web, but I'd recommend to stay away from the Java EE tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you post, what you need to do is program a servlet, in that servlet you would have your business logic calls (in this case the data base query), after getting the data, you have to pass it to the JSP page. With servlets there is no need for main method, but they must be deployed in a servlet container (like Tomcat).

Here is the code:

public class UserListServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {  
    //Accessing driver from JAR
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
    //jdbc:mysql://host_name:port/dbname
    //Driver name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");

    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select name from user");
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    //creates a list with the user names
    List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(result.next()) {
        userList.add(result.getString(1));
    }
    //passing the data to the JSP
    request.setAttribute("users", userList);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user_list.jsp").forward(request, response);  
}  

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)                           throws ServletException, IOException {  
    processRequest(request, response); 
}  

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                                throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

}

Now in the JSP you could have something like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>User List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        if (request.getAttribute("userList") != null) {
            List<String> users = request.getAttribute("userList");
        %>

        <h1>Users: </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Name<</td>
            </tr>

            <% for (String name : users) {%>

            <tr>
                <td><%= name%></td>
            </tr>
            <% }
          }%>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can improve this example by using [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) instead of Scriptlets (<% ... %>).

Comment: thank you for the reply however I'm getting this error when going to run the jsp file:Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to List<String>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667299/java-bean-calling-java-function-and-passing-it-to-jsp/12667464#12667464

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that is this good way to create java websites?

Ask google for Java EE, Servlets and get into it.

Comment: "You're doing it wrong, google around more" isn't really helpful.

Comment: Pass on the question if you can't think of a good answer. This answer isn't what I'd consider "good" even if it's the best you can think of on short notice.

Comment: I was told that there was a mvc structure but really havent found much etc, I'm quite familiar with mvc but am unsure how it applies to java

Comment: @user1393064 Maybe they mean Spring MVC: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html (I'd also recommend searching for some tutorials if it is, the official documentation is somewhat scary.)

Comment: @user1393064 link to mvc http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller